# Must I verify my smart contract made with some OpenZeppelin standards under MIT License?

Tags: solidity

I have a smart contract which use some OpenZeppelin's classes released under MIT License (e.g. IERC165, IERC721, IERC721Enumerable, Strings, Ownable).

It is mandatory to verify the source code on etherscan?

Why?

I don't want that everyone can stole my portion of code.

Comment: It's a hairy issue. See this other thread on the topic: [SPDX license when importing other people's contracts](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/84196/spdx-license-when-importing-other-peoples-contracts).

Comment: "I don't want that everyone can stole my portion of code." - In an absolute sense, this is impossible. In crypto, you're shipping the bytecode to the entire network. True, if you don't publish the source code, it might be difficult for others to "steal" your work. But everyone will be able to figure out, in one way or another, what your code is doing.